# Which format to use in USB BOOTABLE linux? NTFS or FAT32

Tags: linux, live-usb

While formatting USB for making it a BOOTABLE USB for installing LINUX. Which format will be better for my 8gb Pendrive. NTFS or FAT32?

Edit: Using LIVE LINUX USB creator

Comment: The application probably can choose for you.

Comment: Probably none of the above. But you really need to add some more details—e.g., give us a link to the instructions you're using to make this bootable pen drive.

Comment: A normally formatted USB stick cannot be bootable, so don't bother -- whatever you do to make it bootable will just overwrite that formatting information anyway.

Answer (score 11):

You should be able to use any of the 2 systems, but if your system is a UEFI based system, then it will only accept the FAT32 format.

Check the [Wikipedia Article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFI#Disk_device_compatibility):

> The UEFI specification explicitly requires support for FAT32 for EFI System partitions (ESPs), and FAT16 or FAT12 for removable media:specific implementations may support other file systems.